onChange event in TomSelect fill multiple inputs
I'm trying to do an invoicing system and i've been using TomSelect for AutoComplete with the Products I have added into the database.
I have managed to do a working example, but i'm not sure if the solution is best optimised as this app will have plenty of entries.
(nb. I'm using Laravel as a framework)
so the ProductsController method looks like this
public function getOptions(Request $request)
{
    $query = $request->get('q'); // Get the search query from the request

    // Fetch your data based on the query (optional)
    $data = []; // Example: Replace with your data fetching logic
    if ($query) {
        $data = Product::where('product_name', 'like', "%{$query}%")
            ->select(['product_id', 'product_name', 'product_code', 'product_price'])
            ->get();
    } else {
        $data = Product::select(['product_id', 'product_name', 'product_code', 'product_price'])->get(); // All options if no query
    }

    return response()->json($data);
}

... and the script I've came up with
<script src="/tabler/dist/libs/tom-select/dist/js/tom-select.base.min.js?1684106062" defer></script>
<script>
    // @formatter:off
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
        var el;
        var selected_product;
        window.TomSelect && (new TomSelect('#select-repo', {
            dropdownParent: 'body',
            valueField: 'product_id', // Field used for the selected value
            labelField: 'product_name', // Field displayed in the options
            searchField: 'product_name', // Field used for searching (optional)
            load: function(query, callback) {
                var url = '{{ route('get-options') }}'; // Route to fetch data
                fetch(url + '?q=' + encodeURIComponent(query))
                    .then(response => response.json())
                    .then(json => {
                        callback(json);
                    })
                    .catch(error => console.error(error));
            },
            render: {
                option: function(item, escape) {
                    return `<div class="py-2 d-flex">
                        <div class="icon me-3">
                            <img class="img-fluid" src="" />
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <div class="mb-1">
                                <span class="h4">
                                    ${ escape(item.product_name) }
                                </span>
                                <span class="text-muted">&pound;${ escape(item.product_price) }</span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="description">${ escape(item.product_description) }</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>`;
                },
                item: function(item, escape) {
                    selected_product = item;
                    return "<option>" + item.product_name + "</option>";
                }
            },
            onChange: function(item) {
                document.getElementById('product_price').value=selected_product.product_price;
                document.getElementById('product_code').value=selected_product.product_code;
                console.log(selected_product);
            }
        }));
    });
    // @formatter:on
</script>

a short video with what I'm trying to achieve.
https://youtu.be/dCxM0L5RpzY
Thank you!

What is the question? If you query elements by ids, and ids are unique, I dont get the problem

I guess the question is what is the proper way of achieving that same result? Is there any posibility for me to populate the other inputs using another method? I find my solution a bit unorthodox ....
